# Need to set proxy server for apache tomcat in RHEL 7.3

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, tomcat8

I have 3 machines with ips 10.*.*.56,10.*.*.57 and 10.*.*.58. How do I connect all of them using a proxy via tomcat8.

Till now I have made a new file setenv.sh in tomcat8/bin/ folder and wrote the below lines. But it doesn't seem to work.

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS Dhttp.proxyHost=10.*.*.56|10.*.*.57|10.*.*.58 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.*.*.56|10.*.*.57|10.*.*.58 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost"

Let me know if I am following the right process or I need to modify any other file too.

Answer (score 0):

Below link helps you in setting up the proxy with multiple

http://w3devops.com/add-http-https-proxy-http-non-proxy-jenkins-via-tomcat-server/

However, I think tomcat is not the best option to do the HTTP\HTTPS Proxy.
please feel free to experiment with apache or ngnix.

**Apache**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

**NGNIX**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-http-proxying-load-balancing-buffering-and-caching

It may help you one day :)